# Image page break in the print result problem

Tags: php, css, image, page-break

I need to print landscape pictures and need to page break every picture. Now my problem is that cannot page break each picture and the picture size cannot stand at the position in the center.

Below is my coding:

```html
foreach ($row_file_path as $val_1) {
    if($select_page == "1"){
    echo '<img class="rotate90" width="100%" height = "100%" src="' . $val_1['file_path'] . '">';
    }
    else if($select_page == "2"){       
        echo '<img width="50%" height = "50%" src="' . $val_1['file_path'] . '">';
        
    }
}
```

`css`

```html
.rotate90 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    page-break-before:always;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Below is my result:

[image: output]

Actually, I want the result like below sample, can put the image center and can page break each picture, hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem.

[image]